# Why won't my script update on mouse click?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, onclick

I can't seem to figure out why my code won't update. The browser I'm on doesn't have console controls, and I have not other browsers to use, so I don't know exactly what's happening, other than the fact that all of my scripts work except onMouseUpdate/the event listener line. Here's my code:

HTML

```
<canvas id="game" width="500" height="500" style="border:1px solid #000000;position:absolute;top:10px;left:10%">
```

JavaScript

```
var c = document.getElementById("game");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
var ballX;
var ballY;
var ballZ;
var ballXVel;
var ballYVel;
var ballZVel;
var mx=0;
var my=0;
var oldx;
var oldy;

document.addEventListener('onmousedown', onMouseUpdate, false);

function onMouseUpdate(e) {
  mx = e.pageX;
  my = e.pageY;
  renderWorld();
}

function renderWorld(){
  ctx.fillStyle = "#3355FF";
  ctx.fillRect(0,0,500,380);
  ctx.strokeRect(50,100,400,300);
  ctx.fillStyle = "#00DD00";
  ctx.fillRect(0,380,500,120);
}

function renderBall(){
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(ballX,ballY,ballZ,0,2*Math.PI);
  ctx.fillStyle = "#FFFFFF";
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.stroke(); 
  ctx.closePath();
}

function reset(){
  ballX=250;
  ballY=380;
  ballZ=40;
  ballXVel=0;
  ballYVel=0;
  ballZVel=0; 
}

function detectKick(){
  oldx=mx;
  oldy=my;

  loopDetectKick(); 
}

function loopDetectKick(){
  if(oldx==mx&&oldy==my){

    setTimeout(loopDetectKick(),100);

  } else{

    renderWorld();
  }
}

renderWorld();
reset();
renderBall();
detectKick();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply change the line

```
document.addEventListener('onmousedown', onMouseUpdate, false);
```

to

```
document.addEventListener("mousedown", onMouseUpdate, false);
```

I've changed `onmousedown` to `mousedown` and replaced the single quotes with double quotes.